# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS release doesn't boot after being installed

Tags: boot, 14.04

I used Linux live USB creator to make a live disk of Ubuntu 14.04. I booted it up, chose "Something Else" and manually made a 58GB partition and a 4GB swap space. The install seemed to work, and finished fine. But when I boot up into the partition, nothing happens, and it just boots windows??
Any help would be appreciated, thanks, :-)

Comment: Wow, that is a huge swap space you created! Did you install Grub on your Windows partition or did you select the entire hard drive to install the Grub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-installing the Grub bootloader again. To do that use your live USB and boot into Ubuntu 14.04 and install boot-repair with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use advanced options(at left bottom) in boot-repair(not the recommended).

Open advanced options in boot-repair .

`advanced options=>'GRUB location'` (Select "place grub into". Select "sda". Don't select sda1 or sda2 or anything like those numbered partitions. Just choose 'sda' only)

`advanced options=>'GRUB options'` (Select "Purge grub before reinstalling it")

`advanced options=> Other options` ( Unselect the "Repair Windows boot files" & "Check Internet connection" if they are selected.)