# Laptop starts Windows 8.1 after instlling Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I have a new HP Pavilion 15 with windows 8.1, and want to have *Ubuntu* alongside it.
I created an *Ubuntu 14.04 liveDVD*, disabled fast boot, and changed the boot order. Then I installed *Ubuntu*. After that the computer still went straight to Windows (when the DVD was not in), so I disabled secure boot (even though some web pages say it's not necessary - can I put it back?).
After that I followed all the instructions in [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS release doesn't boot after being installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452031/ubuntu-14-04-lts-release-doesnt-boot-after-being-installed) .

After the last step I got [this link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11700675/) with tons of info.

All steps here completed without any error message, but still I go straight to Windows.

Comment: maybe this is the solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help/655279#655279

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there are are two things that could be happening here.

A) You mentioned secure boot, implying a UEFI system. You may have installed the BIOS boot version of GRUB.

B) You need to use a program such as EasyBCD to add a Linux entry into the Windows boot loader menu and make it visible on boot. Just Google EasyBCD for more info.

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with 14.04 on a newer laptop, but from some reading I found that 15.04 has the capability to install with secure boot enabled. I tried it two days ago and it worked just fine. I only disabled fast boot, but left secure boot enabled in UFEI. I have had success installing 14.04 after I disabled secure boot and fast startup. You might want to leave the UFEI in insecure boot and try to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Master Boot Records is damaged.

1. Burn Ubuntu Live USB / DVD (You can do it via Unetbootin).
2. Boot the machine in Live Ubuntu environment.
3. Open up terminal and type

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair;

   sudo apt-get update;

   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```
4. Once the boot-repair window pops up , click on recommended repair.
5. Reboot.
   This might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

according to your report there is *No boot loader installed*...

you have to (re)install [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB), the default boot loader of Ubuntu.

please have a look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: The page you sent me suggests in my case to use boot-repair. I already did that - this is what the link I put instructed me to do.
I did it again, this time choosing the recommended option, and got this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11714911/
Nothing seems to have changed. I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu completely.
I'm new to this, maybe I miss something obvious.

Comment: please disable fast-boot, secureBoot and every other "special" uefi/windows-feature! - or simply try BIOS/legacy-mode! -- further and detailed instructions: http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/354350