# Restoring Grub Launcher After Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I went ahead and installed windows 10 on my windows 8 and Ubuntu dual boot PC. All went smooth and Windows 10 works perfectly however the computer automatically boots to Windows and the grub launcher is missing. The partitions are still there I just need some help getting Ubuntu back. Thank you in advance!

Edit: I found a way around it. I don't know of this works for everyone but I went in to the control panel and went to update and recovery. Then I went to recovery and booted into uefi.  Then I selected boot from device and my Ubuntu partition was there and I could boot into it.  Feel free to post other solutions though!

Comment: The solution you're looking for: http://askubuntu.com/a/655279/228067

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot into Ubuntu using your computer's boot menu (probably something like press ESC at startup.  it will tell you) and run this in Terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda; sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: I won't work since it has something I think is called fastboot or something like that legacy boot isn't on. I need to know how to get to the uefi settings and change that. Once I do that I can run the terminal code

Comment: Ah.  Disable fastboot and secure boot.  That should do it.

Comment: Did this work? Given the this is the only answer here it's probably best to either mark it as solved or give feedback so we can reply for others or continue to help you, please.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help), which includes more details and two solutions.

[Parted rescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/rescue.html) showed my Linux partition as unallocated, but I could see the missing files and folders with [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) so I let testdisk wrote the new partition tables. Hopefully [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) will restore the Grub dual-boot. At least now I can use [ext2explore](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/Ext2read%20Version%202.2%20%28Latest%29/) to copy my work files from Linux to my Windows partition.

Comment: ext2explore isn't stable on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

As long as Windows 10 has been installed to a new additional hard drive, the following sequence worked for me to reanimate an existing Ubuntu 16.04 install beside a Windows XP.

No Linux partitions seemed to be harmed when Windows 10 was placed on an entirely new harddrive.

- install Windows 10 with custom options to new harddrive
- make sure Windows 10 can reboot normally
- install updates and whatever you need
- reboot with the Boot Repair CD (or stick) https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/
- choose the options to reinstall grub

If all works well you can get back into your old install.
I made sure the correct grub was there.

So I did

- sudo grub-install /dev/sda
- sudo update-grub

Reboot and you get grub with options for Ubuntu or Windows 10.

Windows XP is now accessible through the Windows 10 launcher so it is chained.
But now tripple boot to Ubuntu, Windows 10 and XP is available.