# my drive is not detecting ubuntu why?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, battery

I have one ssd in my laptop. it's installed with dual windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04.
it's working properly that when I turn on my laptop that it'll have the option in grub (hopefully I didn't spell it wrong) to launch ubuntu or windows and instead goes to my windows OS directly.

This never happened.

Somehow before this happened, I was using the ubuntu OS and I left the laptop alone for a while.  I believe it went to suspended then into totally dead, meaning the battery is totally out.

After I charge my laptop after a few hours being dead.  This is when it happened, it just loads windows 10 and never go into ubuntu grub and ask.

My windows, I have a software called "Diskinternal linux reader" which helps me read the ubuntu folders / files if needed.  I tried running it and I can go into the folders through linux reader totally fine.

I believe somehow my grub is uninstalled that's why it's not detecting my ubuntu OS?

Can someone give me a hand what I can do to make it normal again that when I start the laptop it'll have the grub interface with few selections so I can select to start up with ubuntu or windows.

Answer (score 0):

Figured from some other posts, it's because of windows 10 update which somehow erases the grub menu.

this post helped me resolve the issue

[Restoring Grub Launcher After Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655825/restoring-grub-launcher-after-windows-10)