# Grub won't load after windows 10 reset

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I had dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 14.04. I was resetting my Windows 10 installation and naturally my grub booting menu disappeared. I tried to use boot-repair from Live Ubuntu from USB, but after restart, it still boots the Windows automatically. I can see the original Ubuntu partition from there.

This is the output file http://paste.ubuntu.com/13238347/. I have two disks 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD.

The Windows is NOT hibernating, I have run `powercfg -h off` and it will boot USB, if the USB is inserted.

I have DISABLED Secure Boot in BIOS.

I did notice something strange however. In my boot order I have my disks first, then USB and then Windows Boot Manager. When I have my bootable USB inserted, it will boot the USB and not the disks, so they can't be booted maybe?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/655279/457247 This was the solution that worked for me

Comment: See also this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/697195/broken-uefi-boot-how-to-securely-proceed  And you may want to houseclean some extra old kernels.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you already disabled hibernation in Windows, please re-check this.
Disable Fast Boot : Open **Control Panel** (the old version - not modern design).
Select **Energy Settings** - enable **show hidden settings** - **uncheck Fast Boot**.
After having done this **shutdown** the machine **completely**, do **NOT reboot** !

**Reinstall the GRUB boot loader** to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.
**Boot from the Ubuntu installation media** - open a terminal and execute:

```
    sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
    for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
    sudo chroot /mnt
    grub-install /dev/sda
    update-grub
```

Note:

`sda` = disk | `sda2` = efi partition | `sda7` = system partition (taken from the pastebin output)

To check and verify the partition numbers use **GParted** (included in the Ubuntu install media).
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in UEFI settings to be the default operating system to boot.