# Broken UEFI Boot , How to securely proceed?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I've got a laptop that dual boots Windows 10 (upgrade from Windows 8.1) and my primary OS, Ubuntu 14.04. I had the system configured for UEFI boot and until this morning, it had worked fine.

I used Windows last night for something, which is rare on this machine. This morning, the computer booted right into Windows. I suspected Windows of messing with boot settings, so I used 'escape' at boot to manually select the drive that has my grub install.

The default grub/boot partition that the computer checks first at start up points directly at booting Windows now --no grub menu. Fortunately, I used boot repair during initial installation and selected the option to have the other partitions 1st sector point to the grub/boot partition. When I selected the root partition, I got a notification from the BIOS that it was not secure.

Before I thought things through, I went into the BIOS and disabled secure boot and tried to boot from the root partition. GRUB came up fine, so I selected Ubuntu and came to my LUKS password screen.

At this point, I thought that disabling secure boot and trying to load Ubuntu may be a mistake. Afterall, whats the point of UEFI if its disabled the second something messes with a perfectly fine and functioning signed boot loader?

I'm sort of at a loss as to what the correct way to securely proceed is. Is there a way to restore Ubuntu without booting insecurely? Suggestions?

-Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I want to address some misconceptions in your question before proceeding to a more direct answer to your main point. Please bear with me....

> The default grub/boot partition that the computer checks first at start up points directly at booting Windows now

On an EFI-based computer, boot loaders are stored as ordinary files on the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) The computer knows which file(s) to launch when it starts because of entries stored in NVRAM, which identify the partition(s) and file(s) to run. There is no such thing as a "default... boot partition" under EFI; that's the way BIOS boots, not EFI.

> I used boot repair during initial installation and selected the option to have the other partitions 1st sector point to the grub/boot partition.

Under EFI, "boot sectors" don't exist -- or to be more precise, boot code is not stored in the first sectors of disks or partitions. It's all handled through files and referenced by entries in NVRAM.

> When I selected the root partition, I got a notification from the BIOS that it was not secure.

You didn't select a partition; you selected a boot loader file. From your description, my guess is that you selected `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` on your ESP. This begins to get to the problem, but I'll get back to that point....

> I went into the BIOS

You don't have a BIOS; you have an EFI. I know that many people, and even manufacturers, refer to EFIs as BIOSes, but this just leads to confusion because it encourages people to drag in BIOS assumptions about the boot process, as you've done.

> I thought that disabling secure boot and trying to load Ubuntu may be a mistake. Afterall, whats the point of UEFI if its disabled the second something messes with a perfectly fine and functioning signed boot loader?

Don't confuse EFI (or UEFI, which is just EFI 2.x) and Secure Boot. Secure Boot is just one optional feature of UEFI. EFI, in turn is a *replacement* for BIOS. Many EFIs (and even UEFIs) lack Secure Boot support -- but Secure Boot requires UEFI.

> I'm sort of at a loss as to what the correct way to securely proceed is. Is there a way to restore Ubuntu without booting insecurely? Suggestions?

To support Secure Boot, Ubuntu uses a program called Shim. In Ubuntu, it has a filename of `shimx64.efi`. Shim is hard-coded to launch GRUB (`grubx64.efi`), which can then call on Shim to authenticate Linux kernels.

Note that earlier I wrote that you probably launched `grubx64.efi`. This will work fine with Secure Boot disabled; but if you enable Secure Boot, chances are `grubx64.efi` won't match the default Secure Boot requirements, so it will fail. `shimx64.efi`, OTOH, is signed by Microsoft (whose keys are present in just about all computers) and so will work. This is the key (pun not desired, but it's best word) to the solution: Reconfigure your system to boot via Shim. You can do this in Ubuntu using the `efibootmgr` utility. First, view your available options by using `sudo efibootmgr -v`:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0007,0003,2003,0001,2001,2002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,276800,1f4000,de3b7563-97f5-48c6-ab7f-2f5d6d57c644)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (08-9E-01-FF-CA-4D)    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(089e01ffca4d,0)IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0, 0RC
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0004* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (08-9E-01-FF-CA-4D)    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(089e01ffca4d,0)030d3c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000RC
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
```

This is just an example, and yours is likely to be different in significant ways. Note, however, that there are two `ubuntu` entries, one of which refers to `shimx64.efi` and the other of which refers to `grubx64.efi`. Chances are you're booting via the `grubx64.efi` entry, as shown on the `BootCurrent` line. The `grubx64.efi` entry is probably first on the `BootOrder` line, too. To change this, you must create a new `BootOrder` by using the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`, as in:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0007
```

You can add other options, too, which the computer will use should the first two fail. Of course, you should specify the numbers associated with your Shim and GRUB entries, not `0000,0007` (unless those happen to be the numbers). Note also that I've specified the Shim entry first with the GRUB entry as a fallback in case that one fails; in theory, specifying *only* the Shim entry should work fine. It's best to include your current `BootCurrent` value as a second (or later) option, since you know it works with Secure Boot disabled. That way, if you make a mistake or if your Shim binary is broken, you should still be able to disable Secure Boot and get back to your working system by using the computer's built-in boot manager or by adjusting the boot order in some other way.

Once you've done this, reboot into your firmware and re-enable Secure Boot. It *should* work fine from that point on.

Comment: Hi Rod, Thank you very much for the very detailed and informative response. I do/did indeed have a novice understanding of the U/EFI boot process but I'm sure I can get it working fine again following the procedure you've laid out. I might be able to ask more clearly, if the shim64.efi file had been working fine under secureboot one day, then fails the next as in my case, is that cause for alarm? I understood secureboot to prevent loading something that has been tampered with --which seems unlikely for my situation. Could Windows 10 have changed the keys that shim is checked against?

Comment: Or...another possibility; perhaps it's more likely I *thought* I had secureboot enabled when I didn't,  and Windows 10 turned it on? Currently, selecting shim64.efi doesn't work under secureboot.

Comment: My suspicion is that you Windows update simply changed the boot order and you need to change it back. That said, a Windows update might have changed the keys in the firmware in a way that would block Ubuntu's Shim from working. I've never heard of this actually happening, but in principle it could. There are ways to take more complete control of your Secure Boot configuration, but they're complex. (See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html) if you want to investigate this possibility.)