# Repair dual boot ubuntu 14.04 / Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have a dual boot system, entering in Grub, with i could choose between Windows 10 and Ubuntu in one ssd. All was fine since november update of W10. The boot is UEFI and when i power the laptop it cant enter in grub and goes to windows ahead.

Ive a /boot partition in Ubuntu. I have some important documents in ubuntu and i need a step by step guide.

If i enter in BIOS and change UEFI to Legacy mode, it gets stuck waiting for a bootable disk. If i change again to UEFI mode it starts Windows 10.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Boot from a live disk/usb**

**2. Mount the ubuntu root partition to /mnt**. 
Find out ubuntu root partition by either

```
lsblk
```

or

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

(Assuming its sda5)

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

**3. Bind mount other necessary partitions**

```
for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
```

**4. Chroot into /mnt**

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

**5. Install grub**

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

**6. Update Grub**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**7. Exit**

```
ctrl + D
```

**8. Reboot**

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work Ive created an usb live:.http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu. Every /dev/sda* appear mounted in /media/ubuntu/02bc.... large name. My boot partition is /dev/sda6, My / is /dev/sda8m swap is /dev/sda7....I can read all in gparted. It gives me error when i execute grub-install /dev/sda  as root: Permission denied error /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesnt exist. Pleease specify --target or --directory. I also tried to run grub-install --boot-directory=/media/ubuntu/02bcda.... /dev/sda . Any help would be apreciated

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13369587/ All my information of boot repair i could get from the live usb. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries i got a solution, hope it helps other people... Similar to duplicated post suggested but bit different as i have an partition for EFI:

What worked for me:

0) If not installed ( i have 64 bits system):

sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64

( this solves problems like Permission denied error /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesnt exist.Pleease specify --target or --directory).

1) Install gksudo:

sudo apt-get install gksu

2) It didnt work for me, but you dont loose anything to try it:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair

Execute boot-repair and use Recomended Repair.

If it doesnt work:

Observation: ( if live cd mounts any of this partitions, unmount them before mounting again in these folders):

4 ) As my / partition is /dev/sda8

sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt

5) This step Only if you have a separate boot partition ( my case /dev/sda6):

sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/boot

**Only if you have EFI in another partition also: mount the EFI partition . This solves errors like seems no efi partition**

sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/EFI

6) Mount the critical virtual filesystems:

sudo mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys

7) Chroot into your normal system device:
sudo chroot /mnt

8) If there is no /boot/grub/grub.cfg or it's not correct, create one using

update-grub

9) Reinstall GRUB 2:

Substitute the correct device - sda, sdb, etc. Do not specify a partition number. In my case /dev/sda

grub-install /dev/sdX

10) Verify the install (use the correct device, for example sda. Do not specify a partition):In my case /dev/sda

grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX

11) Exit chroot: CTRL-D on keyboard exit

reboot

Optional: install grub-customizer in order to alter names and position of the entries