# After running boot-repair, still not booting to grub

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have a dual-boot machine, with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows. Recently, my Windows did an automatic update from 8.1 to 10. After this, my machine no longer booted to the grub menu; instead, it booted straight to Windows.

So, in Windows, I downloaded boot-repair, and burned the ISO to USB. I then booted from the USB, and ran the boot-repair utility, based on the "recommended repair" option. This then told me that it had been successfully repaired.

However, after rebooting, my machine still boots straight to Windows, and does not show me the grub menu. I have tried the accepted answer at [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help), but this does not help -- my machine still boots straight to Windows.

Any advice?

The details from boot-repair can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15495899/

Comment: You can restore missing partition in gap shown in extended partition with testdisk or parted rescue. Then reinstall grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080 and: Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
http://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition/665462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see the GRUB menu, because for whatever reason there is no Ubuntu operating system installed on the disk anymore. Maybe something went completely wrong when you upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. So, unfortunately you will have to reinstall Ubuntu.
I am really sorry to be the harbinger of these bad news for you, but sadly this is the truth.

Comment: Oh no! Ok, well thanks for letting me know. I guess there's no way to get back date from the old Ubuntu installation, right...?

Comment: @Karnivaurus : No, unfortunately not ... I am really sorry ! :)

Comment: Actually missing logical partition is in gap in extended partition. It can be restored.