# After recommended boot repair, it showed there is no operating system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair

I had a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1.

After I upgraded Win to Win10, there was no GRUB entry for Ubuntu (or maybe Ubuntu was wiped, but I didn't notice...)

I searched online and used a live flash drive to do the boot repair. I typed all the commands given by the auto repair choice.

[This is the repair log](http://paste2.org/JVeJK6bj)

But after I reboot, it showed no operating system can be found. I can't even boot Windows. Please let me know how can I solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/779094/windows-10-update-ruined-by-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot.

Comment: You have an UEFI system, not BIOS. But Sony is not UEFI boot of anything other than Windows. Vendors may hide second ESP - efi system partition to boot vendor system files, but your system looks like you had sda1 as ESP, but now have sda3 as ESP. It also looks like you used ext2 for Ubuntu. Default install is ext4, and ext2 is only recommended if you use a separate /boot and only for very small partitions, not main install as / (root). Entries in UEFI show Windows with 3 different file locations, so one may work if based on current ESP??

Comment: In the end reinstalled the system ;(