# will upgrading Win 7 to 10 affect Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, windows-7

Finally they've got me. I *have* to upgrade Win 7 to 10. Not happy about it, but I have little choice. I'm running at the moment a dual boot Ubuntu & Win 7. I have to upgrade Ubuntu as well (15 -->16).

My Questions are,

- What's the best way to upgrade both?
- First upgrade Windows, and then upgrade Ubuntu?
- Will that Windows upgrade wipe out Ubuntu?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help?

Comment: I can't find anything definitive but [this AU search](/search?q=upgrade+windows+10) brings up a few relevant question threads.