# Dual Boot Worries - Windows Updates

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L570 with preinstalled Windows 10 and just managed to install Ubuntu alongside Windows so I am dual booting using GRUB now. Everything works fine and I like it.

However, I learned from other stackexchange topics (e.g. [Trouble with dual boot after Windows 10 update, used bcdedit, now can't access BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001822/trouble-with-dual-boot-after-windows-10-update-used-bcdedit-now-cant-access-b)) and Internet forums that there seems to be a general problem with Windows Updates breaking the dual boot (breaking GRUB or even deleting the Linux partition), but I did not manage to properly understand what the real risks are for the future.

My question is: what exactly could future Windows Updates break for me in the future? How can I prevent this, what should I do to avoid having problems? How would you evaluate the risks of Windows Updates "destroying" my setup?

I have become quite paranoid since learning about this, so please excuse my not-very-precise questions.

Comment: If you have pre-installed Windows 10 then you have UEFI/gpt. It is only with any version of Windows and major updates with BIOS/MBR where it re-writes partition table forgetting to include Linux partition. The Windows update you may need to monitor is fast start up. Updates will turn that back on, and then grub will not boot Windows. But you still can boot Windows from UEFI boot menu may be f8, f10 or f12 as your start to boot, check your manual. May need UEFI fast boot off (which is different than Windows fast start up) off to have time to press any key when booting.