# solved - W10 update prevents Lubuntu from booting although GRUB is OK and partitions are not destroyed

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, updates, lubuntu, windows-10

I recently bought a DELL Vostro 3268 desktop, with an Intel Core i7-7700 and 8Gb RAM.
This is a **UEFI system**.
It came with W10 preinstalled on a 1Tb HDD (= sda).
I wanted my system to be faster and bought a 240Gb SSD (= sdb).

I need to use Lubuntu as my primary system but also need to keep W10 (which I have to use from time to time).

I shrank the W10 partition of the HDD containing my W10 data to have room for Linux and so that W10 plus Linux require no more than the size of my SSD. I created Linux partitions using part of the free space resulting from the aforementioned shrinking and installed Lubuntu 16.04.3 without any problem.
I could easily dual boot from the HDD and select either W10 or Lubuntu 16.04.3 from GRUB, both worked fine.

After having made adjustments so that all relevant partitions be located in the first 240Gb of the HDD, I copied the first 240Gb of the HDD to the SSD with the command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1024 count=234431064
```

This worked fine although I needed extra cleaning steps: I simply had to remove any reference to certain partitions from the SSD table (= references to W10/DELL related partitions such as system backup etc. which I didn't need and which in fact didn't even exist on the SSD since they were located after the first 240Gb of the HDD) and to regenerate a table at the end of the SSD with gdisk (option d). This posed no problem.

I replaced the 1Tb HDD by the 240Gb SSD, and could dual boot between W10 and Lubuntu 16.04.3 from the SSD and use both systems without any problem.

Then came **Microsoft's Fall Creators Update** ("FCU"), so my W10 got updated and Lubuntu stopped working.  Unfortunately, while testing with my HDD, my W10 on the HDD also got updated, and Lubuntu now also fails when using the HDD (which leads me to believe that this has nothing to do with not copying certain HDD partitions to the SSD or with my above "extra cleaning steps").

I have symptoms which differ from what I see on the forums.

My GRUB is fine, it displays the GRUB menu properly, and lets me boot into W10 if I select the W10 GRUB entry.

However, if I select the Lubuntu GRUB entry as I used to do before FCU, it fails with a strange series of errors:

```
[    0.024938] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure,
 AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/dswload-210)
[    0.024944] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (2016093
0/psobject-227)
[    0.024978] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:DELL_SFF) while loading table
 (20160930/tbxfload-228)
[    0.025748] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 9 successful (20160930/tbxfloa
d-246)
/dev/sda8: clean, 289894/6111232 files, 2885028/24413952 blocks
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
```

My partitions are fine (contents preserved, as far as I can say).

I realized that my partitions were not numbered in the order in which they appear on the SSD, but I fixed it: they are now numbered in the order in which they appear on the SSD.

I noticed that FCU had restored "Fast Boot" and the hibernate mode in W10, but reconfigured W10 to redisable them.

I managed to temporarily restore my Lubuntu by using yannubuntu/boot-repair.
But after a few hours, I lost Lubuntu again without any messing around with the system, and got a series of error similar to the above (ACPI stuff).

I restored it again with boot-repair, but it never lasts.

I have no more ideas.

Did anybody encounter anything similar and do you have any idea of what I could do other than reinstall everything from scratch?

I don't need any help for a full reinstall, but this is clearly not what I want to do, since I have plenty of applications and three different accounts on each of W10 and Lubuntu, and anyway I have no reason to believe that this would solve my problem...

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Edit:
As explained in my initial post (title + body, see above), GRUB loads without problem. I can boot into W10 via GRUB. This is not a duplicate.

Edit #2:
I tried to boot-repair.
This time I failed to restore my Lubuntu (I tried three times, but not all possible options).
I attached a pastebin anyway, in case it helps: paste.ubuntu.com/p/F2yJVx9Gzn

I think this failure may be due to the fact that last time I restored my Lubuntu I had requested boot-repair to repair Windows too (although it worked fine), which I didn't request this time.
My W10 works fine while I remember that last time I fixed Lubuntu I had to play with bcdedit in Windows and I had been scared (at some point) to kill both W10 and Lubuntu.

I tried the default options of boot-repair too, but this failed with the following error:
"grub-efi-amd64-signed purge cancelled. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com" (I didn't report this message at that stage, not knowing whether this is relevant & I don't want to spam).

In view of the pastebin, do you have more elements to provide some hints as to how to repair my Lubuntu?

BTW, when I boot via the live Lubuntu DVD, I also have some ACPI errors (possibly the same as indicated in my initial post - they disappeared before I had the time to take a picture to verify that), and this does not affect booting or using the live DVD, so the problem must be something else. The ACPI errors seem to be due to some USB hardware (but I have noticed no pb with my USB ports in W10 or in Lubuntu) and can likely be ignored.

Thanks!

Comment: Dell defaults to RAID or Intel SRT. But you need AHCI. Either Dell update to UEFI or Windows update may reset some UEFI settings. Check that drives are still AHCI and Windows fast start up is off. Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair if not UEFI settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate, as explained in my initial post (both in the title and in the body), because in the issue referred to by karel, the OP says "Grub no longer appeared on boot". As explained in my post, I do have GRUB on boot and I can boot to W10 without any problem via GRUB.

Comment: To olfred: in UEFI, my SATA controller is set to AHCI. As indicated in my post, Windows "Fast boot" is off. So is secure boot. I will run through boot-repair again and post a summary report asap (hopefully within 24h). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to restore Lubuntu.
I am not able to determine how  FCU could be responsible for my problem, although the problem occurred when installing FCU.
Maybe Microsoft had nothing to do with my problem...
I am even less able to explain how I have been able to solve the issue in the past with boot-repair (and then it failed again).

The reason was my fstab which contained a bogus entry for mounting the local DVD for LTSP (the PC has two NICs and is an LTSP server for which I needed a special setup for the server's DVD drive).
I simply had to remove the line and I am now able to boot normally (now I will need to figure out how to restore the LTSP feature, but this is another story...).