# What kind of machine can I use to install Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, lubuntu

I have already followed a process for instaling Ubuntu by myself without knowing anything about this OS back in 2005 (I had background for installing OS s.a FreeBSD 4.2). My machine was bought on 2005 (old one) and was HP AMD 64 (now the machine does not work anymore and, I want to change it). I heard that there was issues around 2015 by installing Ubuntu on machine by erasing Windows 10 on machine bought after 2015. Some disk were crashed and computers were unusable… Now I know that it can be install on Windows 10 (w10) with virtual machines by following some specific steps/process... I read some blogs with dual boot options [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010452/solved-w10-update-prevents-lubuntu-from-booting-although-grub-is-ok-and-partit) for instance...  But what if I don’t want to use w10 and install ubuntu only on the disk? Do you have any machine name/brand that I can buy?
I went [here](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop) but it is hard to made up my mind. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advence,

SDO

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about hardware recommendation.

Comment: This is not a forum, but a Q&A site for Ubuntu and *official flavors* of Ubuntu. Your question's is really an opinion (thus off-topic) geared one, and hardware recommendations are off-topic too (see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), but had your question been asked in a more appropriate place I'd have responded differently (Ubuntu Forums would have made more sense.. I'm also aware a Lubuntu team member purchased a new machine a few months ago for testing Lubuntu on.. a new device, so had it been asked on the Lubuntu discourse you may have got responses from someone who recently purchased)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any problem installing Ubuntu on most Win10 PCs, regardless whether you want to keep Win10 or erase the disk and install Ubuntu. Ubuntu's shim bootloader is signed by Microsoft (same as various other Linux distros), so you won't even have to disable Secure Boot. Installing and running Linux have never been easier!

As a rule of thumb, as long as you're buying from an established PC brand (HP, Lenovo, Dell, Asus, Acer, etc), everything should work. Don't buy Microsoft Surface laptops. They have various hardware (WiFi, webcam, touchscreen etc.) that isn't well supported. I suggest you choose a model you like and then search the Web for people sharing their experience of running Linux on it.

Comment: thanks a lot Igor. The things that scared me was that different vendors told me it was possible but when I asked them "Did you do install Ubuntu on your machine (alone no win10 for PC)" they told me no. Off course many solutions exists...
Take care ;-)

Comment: Actually I remember Lenovo had some laptops with no OS preinstalled. I bought one such laptop (IdeaPad Z580) back in 2013. It works to this day with Ubuntu :) Lenovo's ThinkPads are renowned in the Linux world for their ease of use with Linux.