# Dual-boot Os upgrading windows alongside ubuntu

Tags: 17.10, windows-7, windows-10

I have a simple question i think .I have dual-boot Os Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 17.10 and now i want to upgrade my windows 7 home permium to windows 10 without corrupting Linux Ubuntu But i Don't know how to upgrade it.
-sorry for noob question

Comment: You won't find on this site documentation on how to upgrade Windows. Nevertheless if you [follow this](https://www.howtogeek.com/226295/how-to-upgrade-a-linux-dual-boot-system-to-windows-10/) and Windows overwrite GRUB you may need to [read this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/655279/349837).

Comment: @PabloBianchi thanks for the answer maybe it will help me