# Dual boot Ubuntu (on HDD)/Windows (on SSD) with GRUB

Tags: grub2, windows, hard-drive, ssd

I think that my situation is a bit tricky but I am not used to this kind of operations so I could make some mistakes and I apologise.

A week ago I had a dual boot, with GRUB that was installed on the SSD (so it started faster). When booting, I used to chose between Ubuntu 17.04 (Installed on a partition of an HDD, that has MBR) and Windows 10 (Installed on the SSD, **NOT** MBR).

Now I have reinstalled Windows and GRUB is not there anymore, since I wiped the drive. I would like to restore that dual boot, I tried from a live version of Ubuntu with disk-repair tool but I did not managed to. I don't know what to do and I hope someone has got some clues.

Thanks in advance for reading this.

Comment: Are both systems UEFI or both BIOS boot? What brand/model system? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Windows, it replaced GRUB with the Windows bootloader.

Try [this from Ubuntu LiveCD](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/847151), or [this from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/a/655279/847151).

Another option is to boot from Ubuntu LiveCD, mount the old Linux partition, save your files and then wipe it and reinstall Ubuntu alongside with Windows.