# Not able to get where is ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-one

One year ago I had installed ubuntu 17.10 in my windows 10 system. I am ubuntu user only. Today when I opened my system, everything was lost , no page to select the OS was coming. It directly opened windows. 
Can anyone please tell me waht must be the problem?

Comment: When you say "in" Windows, you don't mean in a virtual machine, right?

Comment: Have you changed any BIOS/UEFI settings recently?

Comment: Check boot order in bios settings

Comment: My guess is a Windows update set itself up as the defacto OS. If so this might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help