# Windows 10 update killed grub, basic repair failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I had an update on Windows and since then grub fails to load.

First I got into Ubuntu using the advanced start-up options and ran boot-repair. Didn't help

Second I tried reinstalling Ubuntu and restoring Windows to the original configuration (they needed cleaning up anyway). Grub still failed to load on startup.

Looking in the BIOS my boot order has various devices, Network and OS Boot Manager, I've tried putitng all of them first but grub still doesn't load.

Then I ran out of ideas. I saw [this reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help), but it's 4 years old. Is it still valid? (am scared of bricking my laptop)

Attached screenshots of my partitions, there are Windows partitions, one for my files, and one for Ubuntu. Grub is installed on sda. The one called RECOVERY I don't know what it is, I'm sure it wasn't there before.

Partitions seen in Ubuntu
[image: partitions seen in Ubuntu]

Partitions seen in Windows
[image: partitions seen in Windows]

Comment: Thank you PRATAP. Do you also know or have some suggestions how to get my grub working again please?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers who have the same problem I can cnofirm that the solution [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help) works also now in 2019 after umpteen updates of Windows 10.

For ease of reading I'm reposting the command from the linked thread that brought back my grub

> run this in Windows as an administrator:
>
> `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`