# Can't boot in Ubuntu after Windows Update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount

I have a problem with my Dual-boot System (installed on one SSD) Ubuntu and Windows 10. It worked fine until Windows 10 got an update recently. After that when trying to boot into Ubuntu I go straight to the Grub 2.02 Terminal.

I know that there are multiple posts about this topic but none of the suggested fixes worked for me because of different problems:

1. First I tried to locate the boot folder in the Grub Terminal following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot) :

   - `ls` gave me the different partitions: (hd0, gpt1) .... (hd0, gpt6), (hd0, msdos1)..(cd0).
   - When I tried to access any partitions with e.g `ls hd0` or `ls gpt2`, I get the error `file system is FAT` (for gpt2) or `file system is unknown` (for all other ones)
2. The second thing I tried is to make an automatic Boot-Repair from a Ubuntu Live Version. After finishing it said "Boot-repair successfull" and gave me the following [log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KdqpdCP3j8/).
   Needless to say, the problem still presists unchanged.
3. The third thing I tried was following [this approach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432):

`sudo fdisk -l` gives me:

```
/dev/sda1      R          2,048       923,647       921,600 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)  
/dev/sda2               923,648     1,126,399       202,752 EFI System partition  
/dev/sda3             1,126,400     1,159,167        32,768 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)  
/dev/sda4             1,159,168   825,810,766   824,651,599 Data partition (Windows/Linux)  
/dev/sda5   +  R    825,810,944   827,076,607     1,265,664 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)  
/dev/sda6           827,078,656 1,024,581,631   197,502,976 Data partition (Linux)
```

So I guess I have an EFI Partition so according to the instructions I tried to mount sda2 with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
```

gives me:

```
mount: mount point /dev/boot/efi does not exist
```

Also, when entering:

```
for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
```

I get:

```
mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist  
mount: mount point /mnt/sys does not exist  
mount: mount point /mnt/run does not exist  
mount: mount point /mnt/proc does not exist
```

However, when I try `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`, it works but I can't go any further as the steps from step 4 on don't work (as described above).

So that's the problem.

Please note that I´m a beginner when it comes to Ubuntu. My apologies if the problem is really obvious and I'm just missing something.

Any help is really appreciated! Also, simply reinstalling Ubuntu is not really an option as the install has important data for my master thesis on it which I really don't want to lose. I just was on my way to making a backup of the data when the problem occurred..:(

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: Did you try to change the boot order (make Ubuntu the first) from the BIOS menu?

Comment: not a fix for booting, but if you just need the data on the partition you could try [accessing it from Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/). Also for the future, I'd highly recommend creating an OS partition, and a data partition. That way you can wipe the OS without losing the data. Good Luck!

Comment: @singrium Yes, Ubuntu is first in the boot order

Comment: @Smurfz87 Thanks! Im gonna try Ext2Fsd, the other two I tried already but they didnt work...

Comment: Mount points are nothing but folders. The mount points do not exist means there is no directory and subdirectory by those names in side the directory `/mnt`. Use `sudo -p mkdir /mnt/boot/efi` to create the `boot` folder inside the `/mnt` folder and the `efi` folder inside the `boot` folder. Use `sudo mkdir /mnt/dev`, `sudo mkdir /mnt/sys`, etc to create the other needed folders to be used as mount points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)