# Grub/WindowsBoot and dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, windows-10

I've got this error...
I've tried to install lubuntu 19.04 on my pc (not efi) running W10.

after installation everything works fine, but after reboot I got this "strange" error:

my pc automatically open W10 and I got stuck on "Automatic Repair mode" and I wasn't able to run Grub.

I run Boot-Repair and I finally get my Lubuntu back... but I had to remove w10...

my questions are:
why did I get this problem? (in my other pc's everything went fine)...

is it possible to install W10 dual-boot with Lubuntu 19.04?
thank for your answers

Comment: In the event that Grub doesn't automatically appear after a restart.   See https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time.   One of the answers to this post may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)