# Ubuntu+Win10 dual boot stopped working after Win10 version 1909 update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, updates, windows-10

This is my first question, so maybe I'm gonna do something wrong. I ask pardon in advance.

I've performed a proper dual boot installation of Ubuntu 18.04 alongside with Win10 (which was already installed on my PC) and it worked great for a couple of months. After I installed the latest Win10 update (to version 1909), Ubuntu can't even boot anymore.

Maybe I need to update the Grub, but I don't know how to do since I can't start Ubuntu.

Here is a pic of what I see on my monitor while Ubuntu is trying to boot:

can't move forward from here
[image: can't move forward from here]

Please, I really need to solve the problem asap, 'cause I need both of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)