# Repair Windows bootmgr file path from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

So, while trying to recover by (K)Ubuntu from a broken grub after a Windows reset, I have managed to mess up Windows now (oh, the ping pong).

What I did was follow the recommended solution here: [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help), which somehow got me back my grub to usable state and boot into my Kubuntu just normally. (I also needed to revert the bios change to AHCI instead of RAID)

But now, the EFI config looks like this:

```
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,05a8d81b-2be5-4f2c-bd46-b3efe4f7e130,0x800,0x154000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
```

Well, yes, I was stupid to do that. (In my defense, that is what `bcdedit /enum firmware` gave me as the only option having something with Ubuntu, and I was desperate. )

Now the question is that: how can I change the file path back to what it should be. I am looking for basically a `bcdedit` equivalent in Linux.

Does anyone have suggestions? I've seen another post that talks about https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr. I have a couple of issues with that:

1. It's Gentoo. I don't have a long beard yet.
2. Even if I couraged up a bit, it doesn't seem to have an `edit` mode.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, boot-repair has this in the advanced-options. It even has a name: "hard-coded-EFI error".

[image]

Strangely however, just this didn't fix it for me. I had to go through a few rounds (yes, somehow one wasn't enough) attempts at Windows repair though the grub options for Windows with Dell. And after a couple of days, windows just boots like nothing happened.

I was almost on the verge of resetting the Windows itself, but I backed off last minute because I was not sure if the reset would remove my linux partitions as well. So it just did a boot repair from Windows again and after that I was able to boot.

Can't be conclusive what worked. But, a boot repair advanced option and few runs of Windows boot repair can't do much harm.