# Grub does not appear after updating Windows10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-10

I have a dual-boot and after updating Windows 10 my Grub stopped showing and the Windows 10 is initialized without any options to boot. (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04)

I already tried using an USB to install boot-repair and followed all the instructions.

I also executed  bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi as admin on my Windows 10, it said the command was executed successfully but when I rebooted the system, it did not work

If you want to check the boot-repair log, here it is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZxspfZBrTP/

I just want to know how can I start my Ubuntu (even if it means removing windows or something like this)

Comment: I also disabled fast boot option, security boot option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)

Comment: Windows updates reset it to first in boot order, just like major grub update will reset it to first in boot order. And Windows updates turn fast start up back on which prevents grub from booting Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
You also have a Windows UEFI entry line 32 in report that boots Ubuntu. You should remove it and only keep Windows entry using bootmgfw.efi as in line 34.