# Dual boot - Ubuntu 20.04 EFI\UBUNTU\grubx64.efi - Not found

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, uefi, windows-10

I encountered this problem while starting my notebook today:

```
Failed to open \EFI\UBUNTU\grubx64.efi - Not found 
Failed to load image \EFI\UBUNTU\grubx64.efi: Not found 
start_image() returned Not found
```

I use Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

First I tried solutions provided here: [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help?fbclid=IwAR0yUkjd5VJ86kY-Etm1ayhOURjj6qwLIUKoIphpTLTNaWFx-sqouwN0LJs)

By running `bcdedit /enum firmware` to determine the correct path for system and then tried running:

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI`

Didnt help. After i rebooted, I received the message again after which it boots me into Windows 10, without letting me access Ubuntu.

Comment: What brand/model system? Both Windows & Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode? Selecting "ubuntu" entry in UEFI one time boot key? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve just by running Boot repair on bootable USB with recommended repair.