# No GNU GRUB after dual boot setup ( Boots directly to Windows10)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I just installed a fresh Windows 10 on my PC alongside with it I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. My problem no is that it directly boots into Windows and I dont get the GNU GRUB Bootloader where i can decide which OS i want to use I can boot into ubuntu by hitting my BIOS key. The PC then asks me if i want to boot Windows or Ubuntu or enter setup. But i cant see a Solution where I can get the Bootloader. Maybe someone encountered the same issue before and can help me to fix it I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)

Comment: Also turn of Fast Boot option in Windows. Some updates reenable this option automaticly. Can you go into the UEFI ( some people still call this incorrectly BIOS ) and choose Ubuntu? When, does this then give you the Grub menu?

Comment: Just turned of fast boot and switched in UEFI from CSM to UEFI still no GRUB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please check your computer's bios has a UEFI or legacy EFI bootloader. You need to check the boot menu (F9, Esc, etc... depending on your PC manufacturer) and look for the Ubuntu Boot entry. If so, select it, you should see the grub menu and your computer should boot into Ubuntu. After that, you can change the boot order using the [efibootmgr](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr) command with root (sudo) privileges. if not (the Ubuntu Boot menu does not show up), you have to use an Ubuntu live (cd or usb) and use the [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: In UEFI it was CMS/UEFI i switched to UEFI now and diabled fast boot what you mean looking for the boot entry? How can i find it there.

Comment: Hello again. I solved it thanks for your help there. I had to go to advanced options and there i could switch ubuntu with Windows Boot Manager in the order so Ubuntu is now on the first option. Now im able tosee the grub menu and choose the option. Do i still have to change the Boot order not with efibootmgr?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your UEFI set-up and select boot options, there should be 3 options.
One is Windows, two Ubuntu and the third is UEFI OS. You want to have this as the 1st Boot option.
This will give you the boot manager at boot.