# windows 11 and ubuntu 22.04 dual boot problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, grub-efi

My laptop used to dual boot normally, but after I updated windows 11 yesterday, the laptop does not allow me to select the OS to run. It starts straight to windows 11. I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/editing-boot-options) but couldn't solve the problem. What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Thanks @user68186, but this could not answer my problem. However, I managed to get the grab manually. The problem now is that I have to do it manually either way it will just go straight to windows 11.

Comment: Trying to solve this, I could only manage to get the GNU grub manually. I doesn't come up automatically as it's supposed to. This is how I did:

Comment: Read all the answers. First: [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in Ubuntu after manually booting Ubuntu. Or better, boot from the Live Ubuntu Install USB using the **Try Ubuntu** option (Do not install Ubuntu). Once Ubuntu boots install the boot-repair app following instructions in the links above. Then click on the **Recommended Repair** button.

Comment: Here is another possible duplicate of this question with various solutions to try: [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help).

Answer (score 0):

Could you check boot order or boot priorities on BIOS(UEFI) menu? Maybe, you can select OS.

I also faced similar situation. But, in my case, Ubuntu wake up. So, I tell the way to allow OS selection on grub menu from Ubuntu side. Grub 2 does not detect otat default. Please try `rm /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `sudo update-grub`. Maybe, update-grub will find Windows boot manager. Then, you can select OS on grub menu.