# Another Boot Issue

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a Windows 7 (originally) Laptop that I deleted the Windows OS and opted for the full Ubuntu hard install.  Everything went fine, however Ubuntu will not boot from the HDD.  I went into Bios and set my boot order to boot the HDD first.  Still wont boot.  I can get into the Grub, however (dont tease me, haha) I am a Noob with Linux and computers in general so I have no idea how to use the grub or command prompt.  What are some tips or command line entry to get whatever I need (like a graphics driver or something) to start this sucker up?  I should mention that I can load the DVD that has the Ubuntu install and boot it up if I "try Ubuntu without installing" option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors when trying to boot Ubuntu from HDD?

[Copy paste solution from this link:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452031/ubuntu-14-04-lts-release-doesnt-boot-after-being-installed)

> Try re-installing the Grub bootloader again. To do that use your live USB and >boot into Ubuntu 14.04 and install boot-repair with the following commands:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
> `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
> Use advanced options(at left bottom) in boot-repair(not the recommended).
>
> Open advanced options in boot-repair .
>
> `advanced options=>'GRUB location'` (Select "place grub into". Select "sda". >Don't select sda1 or sda2 or anything like those numbered partitions. Just >choose 'sda' only)
>
> `advanced options=>'GRUB options'` (Select "Purge grub before reinstalling it")
>
> `advanced options=> Other options` ( Unselect the "Repair Windows boot files" & >"Check Internet connection" if they are selected.)

Comment: I have figured this issue out.  The aftermarket 2T hard drive is bad.  I wiped it clean and tried to put Windows 7 back on and it did not work.  I have ordered another HDD.  I will see if I can install Ubuntu once I receive the new one.   Thank you for the reply.